# Смена цвета разным текстам с одинаковым именем класса(Всплытие и погружение)

Tags: javascript

Всем счастья и здоровья! Создал скрипт, который при наведении на блок изменяет цвет текста на красный, а затем сбрасывает его.
**По задумке, скрипт должен менять цвет тексту только тому блоку на который навелся курсор.**

Но у меня меняется цвет текста только первого блока слева от экрана и еще цвет меняется, если навести на два соседних блока. **Как исправить этот баг?** Знаю, что можно дать разные имена классов в трех блоках, но это костыль, что если блоков будет не 3, а 100? В этом случае, код в CSS станет очень большим, да и в JS то же.

```js
let News_Main_Block = document.querySelector('.Сategory_Main_Block'); 
let News_Name = document.querySelector('.Сategory_name_1');


News_Main_Block.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){  
let child = e.target.className; 

if(child == 'Сategory_Link_1'){
News_Name.style.color = 'red';  
}
});

News_Main_Block.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e){  
let child = e.target.className; 

if(child == 'Сategory_Link_1'){
News_Name.style.color = ''; 
}
});
```

```css
.Сategory_Main_Block{
padding-top:2vw;
padding-bottom: 2vw;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 30%);
column-gap:1vw;
row-gap:3vw;
margin-left:2vw;
}

.Сategory_Block_1{
background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
border-radius: 1.5vw;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
margin:0;
display: flex;             
flex-direction: column;   
align-items: center;       
position: relative;
}

.Сategory_name_1{
text-align:center;      
flex: 1;                 
display: flex;           
align-items: center;    
padding:10px;
font-size:18px; 
color:black;
font-family:arial;
}

.Сategory_img_1{
border-top-right-radius: 1.5vw;
border-top-left-radius: 1.5vw;  
width:100%; 
height:25vw;                                
}

.Сategory_Link_1{
border-top-right-radius: 1.5vw;
border-top-left-radius: 1.5vw;      
width:100%;
height:25vw;   
position:absolute;
display:flex;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
 
<section class="Сategory_Main_Block"> 

<figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
<a class ="Сategory_Link_1" href="/"><div></div></a>
<img class="Сategory_img_1" src="https://i.ibb.co/ZW3xn2G/5-1.jpg">
<figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">1 ПЕС И ЛИСА</figcaption>
</figure>


<figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
<a class ="Сategory_Link_1" href="/"><div></div></a>
<img class="Сategory_img_1" src="https://i.ibb.co/N9L9rjq/scale-1200.webp">
<figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">2 ВОЛК И ЛАПША</figcaption>
</figure>


<figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
<a class ="Сategory_Link_1" href="/"><div></div></a>
<img class="Сategory_img_1" src="https://i.ibb.co/sHrLCtS/1412772681-kitajskaya-lapsha-v-domashnix-usloviyax.jpg">
<figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">3 КИДО И ХАДО</figcaption>
</figure>

</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) всегда возвращает один элемент.
Для вашей задачи нужен [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) который возьмёт все элементы.

> Ещё ошибка в том, что вы обращались не к карточкам, а их родителю `document.querySelector('.Сategory_Main_Block')`

После чего нужно пройтись по коллекции элементов и каждому назначить `.addEventListener()`, для прохода по всем советую использовать [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Так же советую почитать отличие ивентов [`mouseover\mouseout` с `mouseenter\mouseleave`](https://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave), думаю в вашем случае лучше использовать второй вариант

```js
let News_Main_Block = document.querySelector('.Сategory_Main_Block');
let News_Block = document.querySelectorAll('.Сategory_Block_1');


News_Block.forEach(function (e) {
  
  e.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
    let target = e.target,
        name = target.querySelector('.Сategory_name_1');

    if(name) {
      name.style.color = 'red';
    }
  });

  e.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
    let target = e.target,
        name = target.querySelector('.Сategory_name_1');

    if(name) {
      name.style.color = '';
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.Сategory_Main_Block {
  padding-top: 2vw;
  padding-bottom: 2vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 30%);
  column-gap: 1vw;
  row-gap: 3vw;
  margin-left: 2vw;
}

.Сategory_Block_1 {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border-radius: 1.5vw;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.Сategory_name_1 {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  font-family: arial;
}

.Сategory_img_1 {
  border-top-right-radius: 1.5vw;
  border-top-left-radius: 1.5vw;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25vw;
}

.Сategory_Link_1 {
  border-top-right-radius: 1.5vw;
  border-top-left-radius: 1.5vw;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25vw;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section class="Сategory_Main_Block">

  <figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
    <a class="Сategory_Link_1" href="/">
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <img class="Сategory_img_1" src="https://i.ibb.co/ZW3xn2G/5-1.jpg">
    <figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">1 ПЕС И ЛИСА</figcaption>
  </figure>


  <figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
    <a class="Сategory_Link_1" href="/">
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <img class="Сategory_img_1" src="https://i.ibb.co/N9L9rjq/scale-1200.webp">
    <figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">2 ВОЛК И ЛАПША</figcaption>
  </figure>


  <figure class="Сategory_Block_1">
    <a class="Сategory_Link_1" href="/">
      <div></div>
    </a>
    <img class="Сategory_img_1" src="https://i.ibb.co/sHrLCtS/1412772681-kitajskaya-lapsha-v-domashnix-usloviyax.jpg">
    <figcaption class="Сategory_name_1">3 КИДО И ХАДО</figcaption>
  </figure>

</section>
```

---

**Ответы на вопросы:**

> Благодарю, почему в моём случае лучше использовать mouseenter/mouseleave? А если блоков будет 100, то в этом случае ваш способ не приведет ли к проблеме с оптимизацией/производительностью?

1. `mouseover\mouseout` вешается на элемент и вызывает событие когда мышь наводится на этот или дочерний элемент, так же `target` будет возвращать элемент на котором находится курсор.
   В то время как `mouseenter\mouseleave` игнорирует вложенные элементы и генерирует событие только при наведение на блок, на котором вызван.
   В этом [примере](https://jsfiddle.net/CbIPoK2513/h07v5e8L/) это хорошо видно.
2. 100 блоков в любом случае будет влиять на производительность, это уже другой вопрос.

**------------------------------**

> А зачем аргумент (e) в родительской функции перебора News_Block.forEach(function (e)? Что выступает в качестве аргумента функции?

Функции могут что-то возвращать ([callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)), в данном случае `.addEventListener('mouseenter')` возвращаешь объект в переменную `e`, в которую мы указали ([`e` сокращённо от `event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/target)).
В переменной `e` различная информация соответствующая выбранному ивенту, но нам нужен именно `e.target` - в нём содержится информация о элемент, в котором данный ивент сработал.
У вас каждая карточка с событием `mouseenter`, если на вести на вторую, то `e.target` будет ссылкой на вторую карточку.

**------------------------------**

> У меня еще остался последний вопрос: forEach это же метод перебора для массива? Но у меня нет массива, или я чего-то не понимаю?

Почти, [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) возвращает коллекцию элементов в [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList), это не совсем массив, но [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) его может обработать.

Обычно такое действие заменяют на `[...NodeList].map(e => {})` - где NodeList "конвертируется" в массив при помощи оператора [Spread `[...]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) и [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) уже проходит по всем элементам.
Но это более новый спецификации JS и без "компиляторов" под старые браузеры, типо [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) - лучше не использовать. Да и пока это вам не нужно

Comment: Благодарю, почему в моём случае лучше использовать mouseenter/mouseleave? А если блоков будет 100, то в этом случае ваш способ не приведет ли к проблеме с  оптимизацией/производительностью?

Comment: И еще вопрос =) А зачем аргумент (e) в родительской функции перебора News_Block.forEach(function (e)? Что выступает в качестве аргумента функции?

Comment: @Хлебушек, ответил на ваши вопросы в своём ответе

Comment: Ооо огромное спасибо, да вы мастер в этом деле =)
У меня еще остался последний вопрос:
forEach это же метод перебора для массива?
Но у меня нет массива, или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Нужно срочно  поставить плюсы этому человеку! Пойду поставлю вам плюсы в других ответах =)

Comment: `...да вы мастер в этом деле` - совсем нет, но всё приходит с опытом. Ответил на ваш вопрос в ответе. За плюсы в других моих ответах - спасибо конечно, но не обязательно. Можете просто их посмотреть, вдруг найдёте что-то ещё полезное для себя.